# Creating an iso from the virtual machine

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox, opensuse, iso

I have openSuse installed as a virtual machine on Oracle Virtual Box, and I have configured some softwares with the way I require.
I need to replicate the similar environment on a new Server (NOT the Virtual Machine). I was thinking if its possible to create an iso image from the virtual machine, that can be used as a bootable image for my server?
If there is, then how can be achieved?
Thanks

Comment: Why not just copy the virtual machine files over?

Comment: Because, I do not want to start as a virtual machine, I want to build the host with all that software configurations. Can this be done with what you are suggesting?

Comment: This is not officially supported, but I was curious about this as well and found something that will probably work. The tutorial isn't for virtual box, vmware, but I think you can adjust accordingly. Course if you had to you could always install vmware player and migrate it over, then follow the link below. http://www.howtoforge.com/converting-a-vmware-image-to-a-physical-machine

Answer (score 1):

`qemu-img` might be what you're looking for. You should be able to convert from a vmdk to a raw disk image.

Then copy your raw disk image (using something like `dd`) to your physical drive.

This might not work as expected; however, there is another way using autoYaST where you can copy the configuration of your current machine and you can then take that config and build another one.

Once the new box is finished then just copy the config files for your programs to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [Relax and Recover](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sle-ha-12/book_sleha/data/cha_ha_rear.html) full backup software which is available for Suse.

- install it on the VM,
- perform your full backup on a removable device (USB stick, disk)
- boot on this device to restore it to your server.

Comment: How do you write the whole backup in 1 .iso with rear?

Comment: rear won't write an ISO file, but still can achieve the purpose of clonig the system but OK, that's maybe not the appropriate response if the intended use case is to create a live OS image.

Comment: Yes it can, I had the problem, and finally the one of core team did a good explanation which is available at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621749/how-to-create-full-backup-bootable-iso-file-using-relax-and-recover-app

Answer (score 0):

I would use VBoxManage clonehd file.vdi output.iso --format RAW or similar. Then it sould be a matter of just making sure the bootflag is set on the media you used for the iso.

Comment: I tried something like this. It did not work. Possibly there is an additional step that would prevent the "Missing partition table" error that I got. See https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/17/linux-v2p/#EFa