# How to create full-backup bootable ISO file using Relax-and-Recover app?

Tags: linux, usb, backup, iso, bootable

I've recently faced a problem in which I need to make a bootable ISO from my current local Ubuntu with all its configs and installed apps, so that I can write it on a USB flash drive and install it on some other machines.

I've searched about this, and tried some of them like `remastersys` and some others untill I finally found `Relax-and-Recover` (i.e. rear) app (http://relax-and-recover.org/) which seems to work the way I want.
The problem however is that, I couldn't make a *single* `ISO` and it instead  generates a 250MB ISO and 1.7GB tar.gz file next to it.
My current config is as follows:

```json
OUTPUT=ISO
BACKUP=NETFS
BACKUP_URL=iso:///run/media/user/myusb
OUTPUT_URL=file:///run/media/user/myusb/bck
ISO_DIR=file:///run/media/user/myusb/iso
```

What I want is just 1 bootable ISO which contains the whole backup that can be bootable on USB stick and be installed on other machines.
How should I do this?
(there are lots of question out there, and none of them has 1 working straight-forward method. I've been really depressed...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling with this need and the problem, I Asked it on the [rear github](https://github.com/rear/rear/issues/2530), and the answer as in the below:
it will generate 1 bootable iso  in `/var/lib/rear/output/rear-YOURSYSTEMNAME.iso`

```
OUTPUT=ISO
OUTPUT_URL=null
BACKUP=NETFS
BACKUP_URL="iso:///backup"
```

And you can install it where ever you want. Please read the issue carefully.
In my experience, if the automatic restore failed, you should manually restore it as the `rear` video says:

https://relax-and-recover.org/

### rear recovery steps:

rear username: `root`

command to restore: `rear recover`

### update

if you want to generate .iso straight into your usb stick, you can do as below steps:

```
# mkdir /other
# umount /dev/sdb1
# mount /dev/sdb1 /other
```

```
OUTPUT=ISO
ISO_DIR=/other
OUTPUT_URL=null
BACKUP=NETFS
BACKUP_URL="iso:///backup"
```